# uninstalling SSRS and SSIS from clustered SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs, clustering

Due to the security recommendation, i will need to uninstall the unused SSRS and SSIS component from a production cluster SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1, so what is the caveats and what do I require to do to ensure the Database engine still up and running ?

Thanks,
Al

Comment: For what it's worth, a quick way to accomplish this is to merely shutoff the SSRS and SSIS services in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Which versions of Windows Server and SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I want to say that you can do this while everything is online, but I don't know for sure. That said, since you're in a cluster scenario, the worst case would be to fail all instances off one node at a time to do the uninstall, and repeat until it's been removed from all the nodes. Do you have a downtime SLA?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008 enterprise r2 sp1 and windows server enterprise 2008 r2 sp1

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these components are cluster aware and they will be separate from the database install, so you would just run the SQL 2008 R2 Add/Remove programs from the control panel of each cluster node and select uninstall for both of these components.  A reboot may be required to take effect.

Comment: Thanks Jason, so in this case I do it for all of my DB instance from the passive node first, fail over and do the active node ?

Comment: For the least amount of downtime I think that would be the best plan.

Comment: Just blast RS and IS. The cluster could care less.

Comment: So did this work for you Albert?